# brew cask uninstall --force virtual box gives Error: undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: virtualbox, homebrew, homebrew-cask

On OSX El Captain 10.11.6, I have

```
$ VirtualBox --help
Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 5.0.16
```

I'm trying to uninstall `virtual box` but getting following ...

```
brew cask uninstall --force virtualbox
Error: undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  <=>
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
/usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox/.metadata/5.0.16-105871/20160414170649.906/Casks/virtualbox.rb:2:in `block in load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask.rb:23:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask.rb:23:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:29:in `new'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:29:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:65:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/compat/hbc/cask_loader.rb:10:in `cask'
/usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox/.metadata/5.0.16-105871/20160414170649.906/Casks/virtualbox.rb:1:in `load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:55:in `load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:168:in `load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/uninstall.rb:19:in `block in run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/uninstall.rb:12:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/uninstall.rb:12:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/abstract_command.rb:35:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:98:in `run_command'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:168:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:132:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:8:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:100:in `<main>'
```

Here is first line of the file it is complaining about :

`cat /usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox/.metadata/5.0.16-105871/20160414170649.906/Casks/virtualbox.rb`

```
cask 'virtualbox' do
  if MacOS.release <= :lion
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

open a terminal and run the following command

```
brew update
brew cleanup
```

remove all the packages with brew

```
brew cask rm virtualbox --force
brew cask rm vagrant --force
brew cask rm vagrant-manager --force
```

remove any existing packages that might have been missed

```
rm -rf /Applications/Vagrant* /Applications/VirtualBox
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/vagrant /usr/local/bin/vagrant
sudo rm -rf /opt/vagrant /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/va* /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/virtualbox
rm -rf ~/.vagrant* ~/.docker ~/Virtual*
rm -rf /usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox && rm -rf /Applications/VirtualBox.app/
sudo pkgutil --forget com.vagrant.vagrant
```

UPDATE:
if you wish to reinstall it run the following commands

```
brew cleanup
brew update --rebase
brew upgrade --cleanup
brew install vagrant-completion --force
brew cask install virtualbox --force
brew cask install vagrant --force
brew cask install vagrant-manager --force
brew upgrade --cleanup
brew cleanup
brew doctor
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: This still leave it installed ? e.g ls /usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox/5.0.16-105871/         
Applications@              UserManual.pdf*            VirtualBox.pkg             VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool*

Comment: it will completely uninstall it since you will delete any existing packages

Comment: I ran your commands and additional had to manually remove /usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox and  /Applications/VirtualBox.app/.  After that I was able to `brew cask reinstall virtualbox --verbose --debug` which previously had been failing

Comment: Can  you add those steps to your answer, then I will accept it. Cheers.

Comment: which commands you like to be added? i have updated the answer regarding your desire to reinstall

Comment: Hi there I had to also manually do ... rm -rf  /usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox && rm -rf /Applications/VirtualBox.app/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion it has been added to answer.

Comment: why would you remove `~/.docker`?

Answer (score 1):

```
brew uninstall --cask --force virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling virtualbox worked for me after removing the offending call to MacOS.release from the old virtualbox.rb script. The file should be hereabouts:

/usr/local/Caskroom/virtualbox/.metadata/5.0.14-105127/20160220202816.699/Casks/virtualbox.rb

With a text editor, remove the if statement and only keep the branch that selects the installed 5.0.14 version.
After that, brew should be able to parse and then uninstall the old virtualbox cask using a simple

brew cask uninstall virtualbox